# SQL query join from table 1 and table 2

Tags: postgresql

Given two tables *t1* and *t2* with the same column names:

places, visits, and types_of_events

The output table should have *places* in the first column.
The second column should have types_of_events from t2.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: When you say "count of ids" do you mean "count of distinct ids"? In other words, should the result contain (A, 3, 2) or (A, 2, 2)?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using!

Answer (score 1):

Use a union along with a computed column to keep track of the table source:

```sql
SELECT
    var1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN src = 1 THEN 1 END) AS cnt_1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN src = 2 THEN 1 END) AS cnt_2
FROM
(
    SELECT var1, id, 1 AS src FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT var1, id, 2 FROM t2
) t
GROUP BY
    var1;
```

For an explanation, the inner union query brings together the two data sets, however introducing an `src` column which is either 1 or 2, corresponding to the table source.  Then, in the outer query, we aggregate by `var1` and take separate conditional counts of the ids for each table.

Comment: @gocode Please check the explanation given at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `union all`, but with this twist:

```
select var1, sum(cnt1), sum(cnt2)
from ((select var1, count(*) as cnt1, 0 as cnt2
       from t1
       group by var1
      ) union all
      (select var1, 0, count(*)
       from t2
       group by var1
      )
     ) t
group by var1;
```

The idea is that by repeating columns, you can avoid the `case` in the outer query.  You can also write this using `full join`.  In Standard SQL, this looks like:

```
select *
from (select var1, count(*) as cnt1, 0 as cnt2
      from t1
      group by var1
     ) t1 full join
     (select var1, 0, count(*)
      from t2
      group by var1
     )
     using (var1);
```

However, not all databases support this syntax.

Comment: @gocode . . . Needed for what?  If you have a different question, then ask a new question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the number of distinct IDs (per table) associated to each unique var1:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.var1, t2.var1) var1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) count1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) count2
FROM
    t1
    FULL JOIN t2
        ON t1.var1 = t2.var1
GROUP BY
    COALESCE(t1.var1, t2.var1);
```

Result:

| var1 | count1 | count2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 4 |
| C | 2 | 1 |
| D | 0 | 1 |